# tcpdf writeHtml() only - overlay images or image and text

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

The task is to overlay image over another image, or over text.
The only allowed method to use is writeHtml().

- I tried padding-left: -XXXmm but it does not work.
- Absulute positioning of images with css does not work either.